# Big IndexBuffer in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'd like to draw a mesh with a big mesh (think ~120k vertices).
If I try to put all the vertices in a single index buffer it won't work, because I'm using a `java.nio.ShortBuffer` as index buffer, so the max is 2^15 - 1, whereas I need ~2^17 vertices. Should I split my mesh in multiple pieces? Can I use other subclasses of `Buffer` as the fourth argument to `GL10.glDrawElements`?

Comment: Which `IndexBuffer` are you referring to ? This is not strictly speaking part of opengl-es.

Comment: Well, opengl-es is probably a wrong tag. Actually, I mistyped that: I mean `java.nio.ShortBuffer` to use as a fourth parameter ogf `GL10.glDrawElements`. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive Edit following miniBill comment !

In fact, OpenGL-ES only supports `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` or `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` for indices.
The most used is `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` which allows 2^16-1 vertices. The other types are only supported by OpenGL.

<strike>You can also use `GL_INT`or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for indices, which, I suppose, you can store in a `java.nio.IntBuffer`.</strike>

Looks like you'll need to split your geometry.

Comment: Actually no, OpenGL-ES doesn't allow `GL_INT` index buffers, according to google. Or at least, it doesn't on Android

Comment: @miniBill Thanks for pointing this out, I corrected my answer, too much used to OpenGL...